# public cloud multi account , with one notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, cloud

my team wants to share a jupyter notebook in a machine learning project on a public cloud provider with multiple accounts , specifically AWS , Azure or GCp .

As I know each cloud provider allow multi accounts but with a notebook for each member , however we need to share the same notebook . Which provider can allow us to do so with the cheapest price ?

Comment: With AWS, you don't really need a separate account for each member - just a separate IAM user.

Comment: You can spin up a notebook on a VM with any cloud provider. Then just expose it to the internet and give your team members the IP address and token. They don't even need accounts.